# Get custom table basing on a variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working in a PHP+MySQL framework; `LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO` is a stored function.

On the base of the PHP `$cc` variable, I write the following query that should return a table like `[id, nome, lev_ratio, nazione]`

```
SELECT id, nome, LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO('test', nome) AS lev_ratio, nazione
FROM 
(
   SELECT nome
   FROM class c join sqd s ON c.id_sqd = s.sqd
   WHERE c.cc_id = '$cc'
)
ORDER BY lev_ratio DESC
LIMIT 1
```

However I get the following error:

> Every derived table must have its own alias

What's wrong?
Is this the right approach or should I create a procedure instead?

Comment: Does `class` is a table ? CLASS is a reserved word, you shouldn't use it in your own database.

Comment: I hope your framework employs [proper escaping procedures](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because being `$cc` in your query is highly worrying.

Comment: @Spoke44 Class is a table, but with a different name. I choose sad name for this example, you are right!

Comment: @tadman yes, it does, btw thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, as the error is trying to tell you, that you should alias the derived table from the nested select.

```
SELECT id, tabalias.nome, LEVENSHTEIN_RATIO('test', nome) AS lev_ratio, nazione
FROM 
(
   SELECT nome
   FROM class c join sqd s ON c.id_sqd = s.sqd
   WHERE c.cc_id = '$cc'
) tabalias
ORDER BY lev_ratio DESC
LIMIT 1
```